# Better Performance in Cosmos-Triggered Azure Function: Deserializing and Modifying Type-Safe Objects, or Directly Modifying Dynamic Objects?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have an Azure Function that's triggered by Cosmos DB changes.

The changed objects are passed to the functions as Document objects.

From a performance point-of-view, is it better for me to deserialize the JSON objects to type-safe objects and modify the properties on those via early-binding, or to keep them as dynamic objects and use late-binding to set those property values?

Answer (score 2):

The trigger will receive an change as the Type `Document`.  If the function parameter is asking for any other type, it will do a JSONConvert before executing the function.  You can let the trigger just automatically do the JSONConvert for you into your type, or trigger on a `Document` and handle any conversion yourself.  Really up to when and how you want the conversion to occur, but imagine more or less same.  `Document` would give you the most control and have the trigger do the least.